# in pylongs, is there a way to loop through all the controllers and actions?

Tags: python, pylons

in pylons, is it possible to loop through all the controllers and their actions?

I want to create a javascript object that has all the controllers and their actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing this under the assumption that you're trying to do a "table of contents" thing. If this is not the case and the below information is not helpful, my apologies.

If you know the controllers you want the actions for before-hand (that is to say, before runtime), you could write

```
def contents(self):
    return [action for action in dir(self) if all(
        not action in ['contents','start_response'],
        not action.startswith('_'),
        callable(action))]
```

for each controller and then have another controller (ContentsController, say) call the `.contents()` method for each.